Использование IdentityDbContext из пакета Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore в чистой архитектуре ASP.NET
Как правильно реализовать IdentityDbContext для чистой архитектуры ASP.NET?
Имеется 4 уровня: Domain, Application, Infrastructure, API.
Поскольку в слое Application необходимо создавать сервисы для WebAPI, тогда как без недопустимой зависимости от нижнего слоя к верхнему получить данный IdentityDbContext в сервисе в слое Application? Необходимо создавать отдельный интерфейс в слое Application, к примеру IUserDbContext (слой Application), в котором необходимы базовые методы из класса IdentityDbContext? А сама реализация будет в
UserDbContext : IdentityDbContext, IUserDbContext (слой Infrastructure).
Только учусь чистой архитектуре, поэтому не знаю как правильно, если я предложил некорректный вариант, тогда попрошу ответить как правильно.
